# Split string at a vertical bar character "|"

Tags: r, escaping, strsplit

I feel like this question is asked a lot but all the solutions I found don't work for me either.

I have a `dataframe` with a column (called `ID`) in which I have a string of numbers and letters (e.g: `Q8A203`). In a few rows there are two of those constructs separated by a vertical bar (e.g: `Q8AA66|Q8AAT5`). For my analysis it doesn't matter which one I keep so I wanted to make a new column named `NewColumn` in which I transfer the first and split the string at `|`.

I know that the vertical bar must be treated differently and that I have to put `\\` in front. I tried `strsplit()` and `unlist()`:

```r
df$NewColumn <- strsplit(df$ID,split='\\|',fixed=TRUE)
```

```r
df$NewColumn <- unlist(strsplit(df$ID, " \\| ", fixed=TRUE))
```

Both options return the exact same content from column `ID` to the `NewColumn`.

I would very much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than splitting you can simply substitute the second part with nothing and it will keep the first ID.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("Q8A203", "Q8AA66|Q8AAT5"))
df$NewColumn <- sub("\\|.*$","", df$ID, )
df  
#              ID NewColumn
# 1        Q8A203    Q8A203
# 2 Q8AA66|Q8AAT5    Q8AA66
```

Please next time, add an minimal reproductible example (your `df` here) to speed up answers ;)

strsplit can work if you remove the fixed option, but you need to provide an exact regex. Also, you will need to work with a list after, which is more complex.

```
# Working with a list
unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$ID, split='\\|'), "[[", 1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works! Also thank you for the pointer regarding the minimal reproductible example . I will do that next time.

Comment: You're welcome ! A good point is also to work string by testing just one. For example, you can test `strsplit("text|text", split = "\\t")` to work out what split value you need. For more information, read about ["RegEx" (REGular EXpressions)](https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_strings.pdf), it's a very complex but usefull tool, and multiple package simplify this